# How to delete the method you create for the Button in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am learning Swift and new on that. I've created this method for the Button in this project. However, I don't know how to remove & delete this method.
Is there anybody knows this question?

[image]

Comment: Have you created this method using Interface Builder? By pressing `Control` button and dragging the appeared connection line into your code window while selected your button?

Comment: So why you can't just select your code and press `Delete`?

Comment: Of course I did, but when I do this and create new method and rename as "method" again, I get an error. My question is that how I remove or delete and create again with the same name by not taking error.

Comment: Could you post the error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that when you deleted the text for the method, the action remained.
In Xcode, If you navigate to the main.storyboard and select the Object that is associated with this action, you will find all the send events in the connections inspector (the icon has an arrow) in the utilities bar (the bar on the right in Xcode). There you will be able to press the little x by the action that should still be present.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to deleting the code, remember to delete the Action in your Storyboard/nib file in inspector menu, see the pic
[image]